# Error java.lang.NoSuchMethodError on my Firebase project

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

i tried to retrieving data from Firebase to recycler-view on my Android project.
first, here's my structure database on firebase
[image: date, nilai, and time are values of data to read]

then, i write Ph class

```
public class Ph {

    public String date;
    public String nilai;
    public String time;

    public Ph(){
    }

    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }

    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }

    public String getNilai() {
        return nilai;
    }

    public void setNilai(String nilai) {
        this.nilai = nilai;
    }

    public String getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(String time) {
        this.time = time;
    }
}
```

to save data, i create PhAdapter class.

```
    public class PhAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<PhAdapter.PhViewHolder> {

    private ArrayList<Ph> dataList;
    public int rowLayout;
    private Context context;

    public static class PhViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private TextView tvNilai, tvDate, tvTime;
        private LinearLayout phLayout;

        public PhViewHolder(View itemview) {
            super(itemview);
            phLayout = (LinearLayout) itemview.findViewById(R.id.ph_view);
            tvNilai = (TextView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.tv_ph);
            tvTime = (TextView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.tv_time);
            tvDate = (TextView) itemview.findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        }
    }

    public PhAdapter(ArrayList<Ph> dataList, Context context) {
        this.dataList = dataList;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public PhAdapter.PhViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(rowLayout, parent, false);
        return new PhViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PhViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        holder.tvNilai.setText(dataList.get(position).getNilai());
        holder.tvTime.setText(dataList.get(position).getTime());
        holder.tvDate.setText(dataList.get(position).getDate());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }
}
```

the last one, my MainActivity class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    TextView txtNilai, txtDate, txtTime;
    Button cekdata;

    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    //get reference database

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler_view1);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

        cekdata = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btn_cekdata);
        txtNilai = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_ph);
        txtDate = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_date);
        txtTime = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv_time);

        //firebase
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("https://raspi-ph.firebaseio.com/Fakultas Teknik/ph");
        FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().setPersistenceEnabled(true);

        cekdata.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        Ph ph = dataSnapshot.getValue(Ph.class);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                        //Getting Ph failed, log a message
                        Log.w(TAG, "loadPost:onCancelled", databaseError.toException());
                    }
                };
                mDatabase.addValueEventListener(postListener);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

but, when i run the project to emulator, i got error java.lang.NoSuchErrorMethod. the error cause by line 42 on MainActivity, is a line to get reference database.

please help me. there's something error in my code?

the error message:

> 07-09 08:45:54.124 6296-6296/com.example.titiarimba.raspi_ph
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.example.titiarimba.raspi_ph, PID: 6296
>       java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method zzbqo()Z in class Lcom/google/firebase/FirebaseApp; or its super classes (declaration of
>   'com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp' appears in
>   /data/app/com.example.titiarimba.raspi_ph-2/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(Unknown
>   Source)
>           at com.example.titiarimba.raspi_ph.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:43)
>           at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2387)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)

Comment: Whats the dependency versions ?

Comment: @Raj firebase-database:11.8.0

Comment: Hey @Mavisa9, did you solve this issue?? I am facing a similar situation.

Comment: @MohammedsalimShivani hello. yes i solve this issue. you can check my answer :)

Comment: Ok. Thank you dear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this question is solve. i downloading google-service.json from firebase console and add it to project/app folder :)

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove your valueEventListener and do this instead

first Remove this listener

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {...
```

change this

```
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("https://raspi-ph.firebaseio.com/Fakultas Teknik/ph");
```

to this

```
    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
```

and then inside your onClick use that reference to access your data. With this for inside your onDataChange you can access all your values from the different keys

```
mDatabase.child("Fakultas Teknik").child("ph").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            for(DataSnapshot childSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                Ph ph = childSnapshot.getValue(Ph.class);
                String date = ph.getDate();
                Log.i("Date:",""+date);
             }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), databaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```

Or you can try to add your reference with `getReferenceFromUrl()`

```
mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReferenceFromUrl("https://raspi-ph.firebaseio.com/Fakultas Teknik/ph");
```

Comment: i still get the error message. i'll post error message on my question

Comment: hai @Gaston can you help me again? i am so confused to show up the data on Recycler-view :(

Comment: Hey, I'm not at home yet, when I get home I take a look at it

Comment: What have you tried with the recyclerview ?  Make another question with what you have done , meanwhile I get home maybe another member of the community can help you before I get to you

Comment: i made a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51359950/data-doesnt-show-up-on-recyclerview-got-error-no-layout-manager-attached-ski

Answer (score 0):

check your dependencies, make sure your Fire base core tally's with your fire base database.

For eExample

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'

not

implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'

Answer (score 0):

I came across a similar error (not the same) with `Firebase` after implementing FirebaseAuth.

After trying a lot, I removed the `FirebaseCore` dependency and it worked.