# NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzx

Tags: android, firebase

I am using

```
pub.devrel:easygoogle:0.2.5
```

and

```
com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1
```

I am making a simple notification app which sends notification from FCM.
I am following [this](https://github.com/googlearchive/easygoogle/tree/9391f7f595b52453567033b3129718e9b034267e) but at runtime i am getting error

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/internal/zzx;
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzaU(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.AppMeasurement.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.AnalyticsConnectorImpl.getInstance(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.analytics.connector.internal.zzb.create(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.components.zzh.zza(SourceFile:28)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.components.zzi.get(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.components.zzh.get(SourceFile:39)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.components.ComponentContainer$$CC.get(Unknown Source)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.components.zzd.get(SourceFile)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.components.zzd.zza(SourceFile:68)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.zze(SourceFile:703)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SourceFile:328)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SourceFile:294)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.initializeApp(SourceFile:281)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.onCreate(SourceFile:37)
                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1748)
                                                   at android.content.ContentProvider.attachInfo(ContentProvider.java:1723)
                                                   at com.google.firebase.provider.FirebaseInitProvider.attachInfo(SourceFile:31)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installProvider(ActivityThread.java:5153)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.installContentProviders(ActivityThread.java:4748)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4688)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap1(ActivityThread.java)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1405)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
                                                Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.apneareamein.autostartapp-1/base.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.apneareamein.autostartapp-1/split_lib_dependencies_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.apneareamein.autostartapp-1/split_lib_slice_0_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.apneareamein.autostartapp-1/split_lib_slice_1_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.apneareamein.autostartapp-1/split_lib_slice_2_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.apneareamein.autostartapp-1/split_lib_slice_3_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.apneareamein.autostartapp-1/split_lib_slice_4_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.apneareamein.autostartapp-1/split_lib_slice_5_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.apneareamein.autostartapp-1/split_lib_slice_6_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.apneareamein.autostartapp-1/split_lib_slice_7_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.apneareamein.autostartapp-1/split_lib_slice_8_apk.apk", zip file "/data/app/com.apneareamein.autostartapp-1/split_lib_slice_9_apk.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.apneareamein.autostartapp-1/lib/x86, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
                                                   at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
                                                   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
                                                   at com.google.android.gms.measurement.internal.zzt.zzaU(Unknown Source) 

                                                        ... 30 more
                                                Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack trace available
```

gradle file -

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion "27.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.myapp.autostart"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.+'

    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.+'

    compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'

    compile 'pub.devrel:easygoogle:0.2.5'

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I have added build gradle file for more details. i extended EasyMessageService for Notifications.

if any more details is required please let me know.
How can it be resolved?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please add your **build.gradle** files code.

Comment: Added build.gradle file

Comment: Looks like your issue is with `pub.devrel:easygoogle` this library, try using firebase-messaging once & see if issue persist or not. more from here : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: Please have a look at [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53444987/4632372) if you are still looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0):

I had also like this problem. I had an old version google and other services such as google service 1.5.0-beta2 Wanted to run on android 10 devices and gave me an error.

```
Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.common.internal.zzx"
```

Then I updated all libraries to the latest version. Then worked.